Using Higher Order Component to implement RBAC in nextjs
I am trying to implement RBAC using HOC in nextjs with react query but the UI exposes the protected route content when i move to and fro between routes. Here is the code snippet. I would like to know what is wrong and how to correct it.
const withAdminRoute = (Component: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    const { data, isLoading, refetch } = useRole();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoading) return
        if (!data) refetch()
    }, [data, isLoading])

    if(isLoading){
        return <p>Loading</p>

    }

    if (data === "admin") {
        return <Component {...props} />
    }else if(data !== "admin"){
        return <p>Error</p>
    }

  };
};


